# Do we need a mock when testing a method that calls a callout class?

Tags: unit-test, callout

I have a callout class that is being invoked in a batch class. I have written the tests for the callout with good coverage. However I can't seem to get coverage on the batch class calling the callout class. Any pointers on where I am going wrong?

Batch test Class getting 0% coverage

```
@IsTest
private class ReadAndPopulateBatchTest {
    @IsTest
    private static void ReadAndPopulateBatchTest() {

        
        String m_csvFile;
        Integer m_startRow;
        Parser m_parser;
        Integer SCOPE_SIZE = 100;
        String CR = '\r';
        String LF = '\n';
        String crlf = CR + LF;
        
        String file = '57,Nadia Tes,,Breec,Breec,03/26/2018 20:59,04/03/2018 04:45,06/07/2018 03:15' + crlf;
        Blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(file);

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new BCalloutMock2());
        Blob fileData = BIntegrationCallout.makeGetCallout();

        if(fileData != null){
           
        Test.startTest();
        ReadAndPopulateBatch obj = new ReadAndPopulateBatch();
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch( obj ); 
        Test.stopTest(); 
          
        }
    }
}
```

Batch Class

```
global with sharing class ReadAndPopulateBatch implements Database.batchable<String>, Database.AllowsCallouts
{
   private String m_csvFile;
   private Integer m_startRow;
   private Parser m_parser;
   private static final Integer SCOPE_SIZE = 100;
   public static final String CR = '\r';
   public static final String LF = '\n';
   public String crlf = CR + LF;
   Blob csvBlob;
   
    
   
   global Iterable<String> start(Database.batchableContext batchableContext)
   {
             
       Blob csvfile = BIntegrationCallout.makeGetCallout();
              
       String m_csvFile = csvfile.toString();       
       return new CSVIterator(m_csvFile, crlf);
   }
   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext, List<String> scope)  
   {
       //TODO: Create a map with the column name and the position.
       String csvFile = '';
       for(String row : scope)
       {
          csvFile += row + crlf;
          csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(csvFile);

       }
       Integer count = 0;
       List<List<String>> csvLines = CsvReader.readIETFRFC4180CSVFile(csvBlob);
       if(count == 0){
        System.debug('Lines ' + csvLines);
       }
       count = count + 1;
       

   }
   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext){
    System.debug(' Records processed.');
    
    }
}
```

The mock class I am using for the Get method..

```
@IsTest
global class BCalloutMock2 implements HttpCalloutMock{
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest request) {
        // Create a fake response
        String CR = '\r';
        String LF = '\n';
        String crlf = CR + LF;
     
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();

       // Zippex sampleZip = new Zippex();
        String fileData = '557,Nadia Tes,,Breec,Breec,03/26/2018 20:59,04/03/2018 04:45,06/07/2018 03:15' + crlf;
        //sampleZip.addFile('All Courses.csv', fileData, null);
        //String res = String.valueOf(fileData);
        response.setBody(fileData);
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        return response; 
    }
}
```

EDIT  - final solution that worked. Edited the batch class that was making the callout.

```
 Blob csvfile = BIntegrationCallout.makeBGetCallout();
 if(Test.isRunningTest()){
            StaticResource sr = [SELECT Id, Body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'Courses' LIMIT 1];
            m_csvFile = sr.Body.toString();
           
       }
       else
       {
            m_csvFile = csvfile.toString();   
       }
            
       return new CSVIterator(m_csvFile, crlf);
```

Final Batch test class

```
@IsTest
private class ReadAndPopulateBatchTest {
    @isTest
    private static void ReadAndPopulateBatchTest() {

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new BCalloutMock2());
       
        Test.startTest();
        
        ReadAndPopulateBatch obj = new ReadAndPopulateBatch();
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch( obj ); 
        Test.stopTest(); 
          
       
    }
}
```

Comment: the preferred solution is to mock the service class/method `BIntegrationCallout.makeGetCallout` rather than mocking the httpCallout itself. That is, unit test `BIntegrationCallout.makeGetCallout` separately (where you will need an `HttpCalloutMock`).  The batchable class doesn't care how the CSV is fetched/generated, it just wants a CSV. Mocking service classes is done with dependency injection which you can Google for examples of how to do in apex

Comment: Ended up introducing a test check to the batch class. see edit.

Comment: hmm -- the if (Test.isRunningTest()) should go around the makeBGetCallout too; that said, read up on dependency injection for the preferred approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get exact same number of API call in test class based on what you set as mock. Solution will be either to set two same mocks, but in this case you can skip calling API directly as you want to test the batch class itself.

Here problem seem to be; your mock is used up for the API call when called directly. Hence when calling from batch class API call may fail and because you just system.log the error in catch, the failure is hidden:

```java
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new BCalloutMock2());

// Skip this
// Blob fileData = BIntegrationCallout.makeGetCallout();

Test.startTest();
ReadAndPopulateBatch obj = new ReadAndPopulateBatch();
Id batchId = Database.executeBatch( obj ); 
Test.stopTest();
```

Quick note: System.debug in catch seems to swallow the errors. You may want to handle the exception in an elegant way.

---

Edit:

If you need to call API directly as well as from mock, you need to set the mock twice as:

```java
String file = '57,Nadia Tes,,Breec,Breec,03/26/2018 20:59,04/03/2018 04:45,06/07/2018 03:15' + crlf;
Blob csvBlob = Blob.valueOf(file);

Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new BCalloutMock2());
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new BCalloutMock2());
Blob fileData = BIntegrationCallout.makeGetCallout();

if(fileData != null){
    Test.startTest();
    ReadAndPopulateBatch obj = new ReadAndPopulateBatch();
    Id batchId = Database.executeBatch( obj ); 
    Test.stopTest(); 
}
```

Comment: I am now getting 'System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.' which is caused by this line - String filename = BIntegrationCallout.makePostCallout(); - in the batch class itself

Comment: How do we mock the part that is returning the blob file? Can we mock without the http mock?

Comment: Seems like you need the result for API call for batch, try setting mock twice, one for direct makePostCallout call and and another for makePostCallout via batch

Comment: I made an update to the post. I am not sure what you mean by setting the mock twice. The first mock is for the post and the second one is for the get. Is that it? I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Please check my edit, if it works.

Comment: It is passing the test but coverage is still at 0%.

Comment: Looks like its making the callout to the library zippex. i added an else if part to check if the fileData has something. and it went to the else part.